# Will sleeping with my son's wife have a negative effect on our relationship?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm relatively new to Crusader Kings 2 and have started as the King of Munster. My first act was to find suitable wives for both myself and my Son and Heir. As my main aim was to expand the family as quickly as possible, I chose potential wives with positive fertility attributes. So I've ended up with a couple of lustful, hedonistic princesses. In other words, they like to fool around.

Anyway, I soon ended up with an event (which I admit I didn't read thoroughly) which saw me having a bit of a late night tussle with my Son's wife. She became my lover and a few weeks later she announced that she's pregnant with my child and suddenly my Crusader Kings game starts to feel like a bad Jerry Springer episode!

My Son is none the wiser and thinks the Child is his. However, should I be worried that some time down the line he's going to find out and our relations are going to suffer as a result? I've no idea what would happen to the line of succession if he did find out. Would the child move to become mine in the family tree?

I tried to Google the answer, which brought up some interesting sites but none relevant to Crusader Kings 2!

Comment: As a side note I'd just like to say the slightly misguided moral judgement of my king does not reflect that of my own ;)

Comment: Awesome question title btw

Comment: I don't know if the title should be worded that way anymore since that act has been done.  I suggest: Will my son find out that I slept with his wife?

Comment: Well, he doesn't KNOW yet...

Comment: If your son stays none the wiser, I imagine this might lead to a complicated succession, especially if you have another legitimate son

Comment: Exactly, I've ended up with lovers which have usually been some lowly courtier, resulting in a bastard which I could legitimize if I wanted. But this scenarios completely new!

Comment: As a side note, I find having multiple heirs a pain in CK2 because you have to spend a lot of reputation to switch from gavelkind (and most likely roll the dice on who your successor is). I'd much rather put a condom on the king after the first son.

Comment: Anyway to answer you you'll have the option of recognizing your son (he becomes a bastard) or to legitimize him (lets him become a heir) at any point later if you wish. Not sure about your relationship with your initial son's feelings, but that covers the succession line aspect of it

Comment: Hmm, I not sure I will. When the child was born I had the "Husband is a proud father" event rather than the "Husband is suspicious" so the child is recognised as the husbands son and of his dynasty (Or my sons son and of my dynasty). I was wondering whether this may reverse in time though.

Comment: I freaking love CK2 questions, they are always hilariously messed up! You say that the child is of your sons dynasty. Does that mean your son is of a different dynasty than your own? Because then the game would end when you die – unless you fess up and legitimize that bastard ASAP.

Comment: My sons dynasty is the same as mine. But the child appears on the family tree as a child of my sons and not my own. So the dynasty is safe. I must admit I had to crack a smile whilst writing the question out. :)

Comment: It hasn't been mentioned here but are you and his with still lovers?

Comment: Yes we are still lovers..

Comment: So even if he doesn't find out this time, don't worry. You still have plenty of opportunities to be discovered.

Comment: Feels like Jerry Springer playing CK2.

Comment: Do you mean Munster, the Irish province, or Münster, the German city?

Comment: Munster the Irish Province.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's worth noting that when the child is born your son will mistakenly believe it is his and act accordingly.

However there is a

- 'The husband suspects something ain't right'
- 'On-action event: Pregnancy in matrimony, with another father!'
- 'The father's wife is angered' events.

So there is still plenty of ways this can go wrong and ruin your relationship with your son. If the child does become your bastard you can choose to legitimise him though. I would see how the new childs attributes compare to your own sons. Then work out which one to favour. You can always have someone locked up if necessary.

Comment: So, the 'The husband suspects something ain't right' for example could trigger at any time? Or only at the birth?

Comment: "Im not your son. Im your brother". CKII is like the dwarf fortress of politics

Comment: So it looks like it could effect the relationship with both my son and my wife depending upon the triggered event. Which may or may not occur. At which point the child could become my bastard...